# Reading tpacket3_hdr from Packet MMAP and getting payload body

Tags: c, linux, mmap, packet

I have a `tpacket3_hdr *ppd` pointer object. I know how to extract iphdr and tcphdr but what if I need the body part of a packet. I am trying like this

```
  struct iphdr *ip = (struct iphdr *) ((uint8_t *) eth + ETH_HLEN);
  struct tcphdr *tcp=(struct tcp *)((uint8_t *)ip+sizeof(struct iphdr));
  char *payload_body=(char *)(tcp+sizeof(struct tcphdr));
  printf("%s\n",payload_body);//Printing wrong Not containing what I am checking by simply downloading html
```

I dont think its the right way of doing this. Full code from Rx Ring from MMAP is given here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/testing/selftests/net/psock_tpacket.c

Comment: Hint: why did you do `(uint8_t *)` on the first two lines?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica to just point to start of eth address and ip s address. Why there something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adapted from Cormen and Stevens, 10.4 TCP Segment Format]

```
    /* The offset of the payload data (in 32bit words))
    ** is tucked into the upper 4 bits of an unsigned character.
    ** Typically (0x5x & 0xf0) >>2 := 0x20
    */

#define TCP_HLEN(p) (((p)->tcp_offset & 0xf0) >> 2)

char *payload_body=(char *)((uint8_t *)tcp + TCP_HLEN(tcp)) ;
```

---

The ip struct has a similar length field in its `ip_verlen` field(version:=4 bits , lengh_in_words:= 4 bits).

For IP the corresponding calculation would be:

```
#define IPMHLEN 20 /* minimum IP header length (in bytes) */
#define IP_HLEN(pip) (((pip)->ip_verlen & 0xf) <<2)
```

So that is the offset (in bytes) where the TCP header would start. The space between offsets `IPMHLEN` and `IPHLEN(pip)` (if any) is occupied by IP-options.

RFCs:

[IP structure](https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791.txt)

[TCP structure](https://rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.txt)

---

This is the layout of a raw segment, as it travels on the net. I am assuming that your file stores this format as-is.

[I would *not* use `sizeof` in any offset/size calculation, since the in-memory structures could contain padding and alignment.]

Comment: thanks for ur answer. where I can get the link of `from Cormen and Stevens, 10.4 TCP Segment Format`

Comment: It is a book. You could obtain it an a bookstore, or in a library, It basically contains a naive implementation of https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791.txt and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.txt (and others)

Comment: Is the book name is`Internetworking with TCP/IP Vol.1: Principles, Protocols, and Architecture (4th Edition)` can u please confirm it.  If not then What is the full name of the book ?

Comment: No, You'll need Vol.2 : "design, implementation and internals"

Comment: In case I need to extract the size of the payload, how do I do it? Does strlen(*payload_body) returns the size of the payload?

Comment: No, of course not. The payload could contain binary NULs (or be not NUL-terminated) so strlen() is generally a bad choice.

Comment: `/* The offset of the payload data (in 32bit words))
    ** is tucked into the upper 4 bits of an unsigned character.
    ** Typically (0x5x & 0xf0) >>2 := 0x20
    */` and the `#define` directive is this code or something when u said `[Adapted from Cormen and Stevens, 10.4 TCP Segment Format]` what is 10.4 TCP Segment format? Is there somewhere like source that u can give me

Comment: It is the paragraph number (and title) in a book by Cormer and Stevens. But you can find the same information  in the RFCs, too.

Comment: @wildplasser is `tcphdr->th_off` is tcp offset field in netinet/tcp.h header file? can u please tell